# How can I prevent Ajax elements from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, ajax, resize

I have a div in an HTML page that is injected with 12 divs via **Ajax**. When I resize the browser window, the elements, or their containing div seem to change size, in which the divs begin to wrap in undesirable ways. When the page is 100% size, the divs align like this:

```
|div| |div| |div| |div| |div| |div|
|div| |div| |div| |div| |div| |div|
```

When I shrink the window, the `div`s align like this:

```
|div| |div| |div| |div| |div|
|div| |div| |div| |div| |div|
|div| |div|
```

So, I am trying to make the divs stay in the first position when the window is resized. I have found solutions like using CSS to set the containing `div` with a fixed width, and using the attribute `white-space: nowrap`.

These do not work for my page however, and it seems that Ajax is the reason. In my PHP file for the Ajax, I have created each `div` to have a link and a table inside like so:

```
    $str = "<div class = 'productdiv'>
                <a class='product' id='$id' title = '$name'>
                    <table id = 'product-table' onmouseover = 'darkenProduct(this);' onmouseout = 'lightenProduct(this);'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>$name</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src = '$img' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>$price</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </a>
            </div>";
```

Here's the relevant CSS for each Ajax element and the containing `div` "products":

```
#products
{
    width: 900px;

    margin-left: 2%;
}
/*product table (ID SOURCE FROM PHP -- for each individual product) */
#product-table
{
    float: left;

    width: 138px;
    height: 142px;

    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;

    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eee;

    /* for rounded borders */
        -moz-border-radius: 25px; /* for firefox */
        border-radius: 25px;
}
#product-table a:link, a:visited
{           
    display: -moz-box; /* for firefox */
    display: block; 

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#product-table img
{
    width: 138px;
    height: 142px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The containing div "products" is nested inside a larger div for the center column. Here is the CSS for that:

```
/* center column */
#center
{
    /* for stretching the center column beyond the window height */
        min-height: 100%;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    text-align: center;
}
```

...so, how might I prevent these `div`s from wrapping, and what CSS approaches should I take?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I tried inserting `<div style = "clear: both;"></div>` between the rows in my PHP file, but it did not have an effect. However 'display: inline-block` for each div's table, `text-align: center` and a specified width of `width: 900px` for the containing div, and a larger height and width for each div's table fixed all of the overlapping problems, and the div's now wrap according to their specified width. When I resize the window now, it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

You should also set their container to a fixed width.  You can also try adding a `min-width` equal to the width.

Edit: sorry, you should continue to float them left.

Comment: They need to be floated or it they would just be stacked vertically, but yes the container should be fixed (and supposedly is)

Comment: Hmm, so I just tried to not `float: left`, and they don't wrap at all -- they are aligned vertically instead. The `float: left` gets it pretty close to what I want it to do, but with errors -- I **do** want them to wrap, I just want them to stay as 2 rows of 6 divs if possible.

Comment: Youre right.  I've updated my answer. Try adding a min-width attribute to the parent container.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but `min-width` isn't working... `display: inline-block` is **almost** working, I have no idea why, but is overlapping weird.

Comment: Well, you can try adding Clear:both to the first div on the 2nd row

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the container has a set width of 900px... the only reason I could see them wrapping is due to them not actually being injected into the container like you think they are, or perhaps some other css quirk with your middle column

When the window resizes, a scrollbar should be added at 900px wide and the product tables shouldnt move at all.

Comment: In my center column I have `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`, would that prevent the scrollbar? Otherwise, to complicate things ha, I just added a CSS attribute on a whim to each element's table -- `display: inline-block`, just under `float: left`. This is now keeping the divs aligned in 2 rows of 6 divs like I wanted! Except the two rows are overlapping each other, causing alignment errors with the content of each div...

Comment: margin:0 auto; is generally used to center an element horizontally, it shouldn't affect whether or not scrollbars show up.

You could try putting a <div style="clear:both;"></div> in between the 2 rows to clear their heights, that may work